# Does Aura of Protection add to my spell save DC?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, paladin, saving-throw

I’m playing a paladin of conquest and am often casting spells or effects that require enemies to make a saving throw against my spell save dc. Can I add my aura of protection bonus to the spell save DC, making it 8+proficiency bonus+Charisma modifier+aura of protection bonus?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Aura of Protection

> Starting at 6th level, whenever you or a friendly creature within 10 feet of you must make a **saving throw**, the creature gains a bonus to the **saving throw** equal to your Charisma modifier (with a minimum bonus of +1). You must be conscious to grant this bonus.
>   At 18th level, the range of this aura increases to 30 feet.

(Emphasis mine)

Note how this only affects saving throws, as opposed to your spell saving throw **dc**. Since it affects only friendly creatures, it won't affect an enemy, so they will never be affected by Aura of Protection.

Comment: And if it did affect non-friendlies, it would effectively lower the DC in this case, not increase it.